# Emmet incorrectly multiplying sibling tag after climbing up when previous tag is multiplied in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, emmet

I'm using the following emmet `header+nav>ul>li*5>a^^^footer` that works correctly in VS Code and there IDE inserts the correct snippet

```html
<header></header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<footer></footer>
```

However, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2023.1.3 inserts the following incorrect snippet:

```html
<header></header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
```

It looks like it incorrectly multiplies the sibling tag. It multiplies `footer`, although it should multiply only `li`.

Is it unspecified behavior, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help in providing all the details. We managed to reproduce the problem and have created a new ticket: [WEB-63351](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-63351/Emmet-incorrectly-multiplying-sibling-tag-after-climbing-up-when-previous-tag-is-multiplied). Please vote for it to get notified on any progress